# How to rotate merge bitmap without being cutted/trim on the side

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, rotation

I merge bitmap using this code

```
    Bitmap bitmapMerged = 
    Bitmap.createBitmap(
    w, h, bitmapOriginal.getConfig()); 

    Canvas canvasMerged = new  
    Canvas(bitmapMerged);            
    canvasMerged.drawBitmap
    (bitmapOriginal, 0, 0, null);

    canvasMerged.drawBitmap
    (bitmapSecond, 
    bitmapOriginal.getWidth(), 0, null);                 
    image3.setImageBitmap
   (bitmapMerged);
```

After I successfully merge the two bitmap (bitmapOriginal and bitmapSecond)

I want to rotate bitmapOriginal but after using this code

```
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
    matrix.postRotate(20); 

     Bitmap scaledBitmap =  
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap
    (bitmapOriginal, 
    bitmapOriginal.getWidth(), h, true); 
    Bitmap bitmapOriginal = 
    Bitmap.createBitmap
   (scaledBitmap, 0, 0, 
    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), 
   scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, 
   true);
```

bitmapOriginal rotated but it it side is cutted

How to fix this

By the way the value of w, and h.

```
  int w = bitmapOriginal.getWidth() + 
  bitmapSecond.getWidth();
  int h;
  if
 (bitmapOriginal.getHeight() >= 
 bitmapSecond.getHeight())
 { 
 h = bitmapOriginal.getHeight();
 }
 else
 { 
    h = bitmapSecond.getHeight(); 
 
 

 
    }
```

[image: click to view image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with the value you are using for w and h.

You are setting the width to the sum of the widths of both bitmaps, and the height to the largest height of the two bitmaps. But if you think about it, if you rotate a rectangle, it’s corners will be outside of where the original border was. See [this image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoLuAbfQToF_mT61gazBSc5qweLSPO8-MxMgrfKwre9jMW8EA6GbUBakGH&s=100) for a visual of what I mean.

The solution for you would be to use larger values of w and h, to allow more space for the rotated corners.